# Flex class directly in html like bootstrap or mixin in scss element?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, flexbox, bem

I'm new to frontend and I'm trying to understand how to use classes intelligently (bem and sass).

I feel like I rely heavily on mixins. I looked a bit at Bootstrap out of curiosity a few days ago and noticed that classes like flex (one class per media queries) are applied directly in the html tag.

For my part, I got used to using flex in mixin and including it in SCSS.

**My mixin**:

```
@mixin d-flex($direction, $justify, $align) {
    display: flex;
    align-items: $align;
    justify-content: $justify;
    flex-direction: $direction;
}
```

**My method**: (piece of scss):

```
 .introduction {
        @include d-flex(column, center, left); //direction, justify, align
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(177, 174, 174, 0.5), rgb(0, 0, 0)), url("../images/header_samus.png");
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        font-weight: 700;
        width: 100%;
        height: 90vh;

        @include tablet{
            height:70vh;
        }
}
```

In bootstrap, it uses already defined classes and applies them directly in the html tag.

```
<div class="d-flex p-2">I'm a flexbox container!</div>
```

Is **my method** correct? Or do I have to prepare pre-defined classesfor each media-queries and add them directly to the html tag l**ike the bootstrap example**?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I might not have understood your question correctly. I also don't know your knowledge on Bootstrap. However, it's a CSS framework that is built using pre-defined classes as you said, those classes you can add to your project as you see fit and also override them in your own custom stylesheets. Having said that, you don't have to follow adding classes in your project similar to bootstrap if that's what you are asking. Since you are using Sass, you can create another mixin for breakpoints and utilize it where you see fit (e.g. to edit the flexbox at a certain breakpoint):

```
@mixin mq($break) {
  @media (min-width: $break) {
     @content;
  }
}

.introduction {
   @include d-flex(column, center, left);
   @include mq(768px) {
     ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback once again. You help me a lot!

Sorry English is not my first language, so I may not be very clear.

I think you got it right :)

I was just wondering if I could create flex mixins that I applied directly in my SASS with an include, rather than creating a flex class that I add in the element on the html.

Your example corresponds exactly to what I do :)

Comment: You are welcome! Yes you can create whatever mixin you like to do what you want! You can also have plain CSS helper classes which is what Bootstrap is in your own projects if you wanted to use plain CSS and add classes such as flex. Happy to help!